# How to say that you can wear a garment "by itself?"

Tags: nuance

I can't seem to realize if this sentence is okay:
(I'm writing about some kind of a top)

"*It is a versatile piece that can be worn by itself or as an overshirt.*"

Q1. Is versatile the right word here?

Q2. Can you call a garment a piece? Or is "piece of clothing" more appropriate?

Q3. Is it okay to say you can wear a thing by itself?

What I want to get across is that you can wear this garment as a shirt, OR, you can wear it as an overshirt. Is "*by itself*" the correct way of saying this?

Thank you

Comment: Your quote communicates your intent well in its present form.

Comment: Yes, it seems fine to me. we wouldn't call a garment a 'piece' in ordinary conversation, but  in the style of your sentence, presumably that of a fashion writer, it's OK.

Comment: I can't think of a better way to say that the garment can be worn without anything over it. I know that I've just used _another_ way to express the concept but it's longer and more clumsy.

Comment: BoldBen: If one option is to wear the garment as an *overshirt*, then I would expect that wearing it "by itself" means specifically that nothing is *under* it.